# How to correctly reference an external JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a JSON Schema for DNS records ([dns-record.schema.json](https://gist.github.com/tomdavidson/9cfee77b84e2ae2d94e59d57e3863db7)) that I want to consume in a separate JSON Schema (dns-tool.schema.json) for a tool I am trying to build. What is the correct way to reference the dns-record schema?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "dns-tool.schema.json",
  "title": "Zone Config Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "records": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        {
          "$ref": "dns-record.schema.json"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These schemas are being consumed via VS Code's JSON service that provide intellisense and are expected to validate data at runtime, but the software is not yet written so in addition to the VS Code "test" I try to compilie the schema with ajv-cli:

> ajv "compile" "--verbose" "true" "-s" "dns-tool.schema.json"
>
> schema dns-tool.schema.json is invalid
> error: can't resolve reference dns-record.schema.json from id dns-tool.schema.json

The files are all in the project root and not an issue of the wrong path.

Comment: Where are you using these schemas? Which validation implementation?

Comment: Just locally for now as I create the tool to manage my domain names, but both are to end up on schemastore.org. json-schema-validator and  jsonschemavalidator.net says its valid, but ajv and whatever vscode uses for JSONSchema informed intellisense fails.

Comment: It's valid the way you have it for most implementations but the reason ajv and vsc dont like it is because the schemas need to be loaded into the implementation to be used for validation.

Comment: Can you explain loaded into the implementation?

Comment: e.g.  ajv has a method `addSchema()` which "loads" the schema into a registry at runtime which is then used during the validation. If you were to `compile()` the main schema and `addSchema(<referenced schema>)`, they would be reachable by the `$id` defined in each schema.

Comment: ok, thanks, just making sure. With the fail present via ajv-cli I think we can rule out whether im using the library correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two things going-on:

1. ajv-cli only references schema by ID so the referenced files must provided with -r `ajv compile --verbose true -s  dns-tool.schema.json -r dns-record.schema.json`
2. VSCODE references by file name.

Solution: Set the ID to the file name, do not use file:// in the URI.  This is only a partial solution because the schemata have to be in the same dir - so even though the answer comes from the OP, I'm not selecting it has THE answer.

Comment: the id/$id keyword is merely an identifier, it's not meant to be retrievable per the JSON Schema spec.  But yes, the referenced schemas should be added to the ajv instance to resolve correctly

Answer (score 0):

The one thing you may need to do with local files is `require()` or `import` the file in your js.

```js
const otherSchema = require('./mySchema.json')
const Ajv = require('ajv')
const mainSchema = {
    "$id": "test.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "description": "This is a schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": { "$ref": "mySchema.json"}
    }
}

try {
    const ajv = new Ajv({ "strict": false });
    ajv.addSchema(otherSchema, "test");
    const validate = ajv.compile(mainSchema);
    console.log(validate = {
        valid: validate
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(validate = {
        valid: false,
        message: err.message
    })
}
```

```json
#separate file  mySchema.json
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "mySchema.json",
    "type": "string"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is not any code in question. Id like to focus solely on the two provided schemas and the litmus test of VSC's JSON intellisense and ajv-cli's compile command.

Comment: afaik, intellisense can't resolve the schema if they are not loaded into the implementation.

Comment: Using JSONSchema for intellisense on json files is built-in (can be used on yaml too): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json  but I can compile via ajv-cli either.

Comment: right, for single schema.. I'm not sure it can resolve references though.  I _may_ be wrong. :)

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't think so and in this case, ajv-cli can not compile either.